# Subscription to rxjs subject get's the wrong type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

My goal is to open a subscription to an rxjs subject, with the type `string | undefined`.

My code looks like this:

```js
import {Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

const a = new Subject<string | undefined>();

// v has type "string", and not "string | undefined"
a.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

[image: Image that shows the problem]

How can I get `v` to have the type `string | undefined`?

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ydca5q) if you wan't to experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have `strictNullChecks` compiler option enabled: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Do you know if it's possible to configure that in Stackblitz?

Comment: I don't use Stackblitz but I would try to add a `tsconfig.json` file with this option.

Comment: It's not possible in Stackblitz yet, relevant stackblitz issue is here: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/220